# В symfony 4.4 не работает supportsClass в UserProvider

Tags: php, безопасность, symfony

После обновления до symfony 4.4 обнаружил что сломалась авторизация на сайте.
При попытке авторизоваться получаю ошибку:

```
There is no user provider for user "App\Security\UserIdentity". Shouldn't the "supportsClass()" method of your user provider return true for this classname?
```

Метод supportsClass() в классе UserProvider имеет такой вид:

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\ReadModel\User\AuthView;
use App\ReadModel\User\UserFetcher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
...
    public function supportsClass($class): bool
    {
        dump($class);
        return $class instanceof UserIdentity;
        //return true;
    }
```

С помощью функции дамп получаю в профайлере, что параметр $class прилетает такой:

```
"App\Security\UserIdentity"
```

Подскажите, где ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй сравнить с абсолютным именем класса:

```
public function supportsClass($class): bool
{
    return $class === UserIdentity::class;
}
```